# MyObject *objectOne = (MyObject *)recognizer.view;

Tags: ios, objective-c

What does this line of code do?

```
MyObject *objectOne = (MyObject *)recognizer.view;
```

I am confused about the `(MyObject *)`.

Is it effectively casting the `recognizer.view` pointer to `MyObject`?

Thanks.

Comment: it will not cast to your object of type MyObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `(MyObject *)` is statically casting `recognizer.view` which is a `UIView` to `MyObject`. This allows you to call MyObject specific methods/properties on objectOne. Without the cast the compiler will only allow you to call UIView methods.

This is potentially unsafe because you are assuming that recognizer.view is of type MyObject. Bad things may happen if this assumption was untrue. There is a safer way to do this.

Define a helper method to safely cast for you:

```
static inline id MySafeCast(Class klass, id obj) {
    return [obj isKindOfClass:klass] ? obj : nil;
}
```

The method will return nil if your assumption about the type is wrong.

```
// objectOne will be nil if recognizer.view is not a MyObject
MyObject *objectOne = MySafeCast([MyObject class], recognizer.view);
```

Comment: Thank you, i'd upvote your answer but I don't have enough points to do so.

Comment: Thank you, one last thing, best practice wise, should UIGestureRecognizers be instance variables?

Comment: @JohnWoods Posting a completely new question as a comment to an answer is inappropriate. If you have a new question, post a new question (after doing a little research first of course).

Comment: Apologies - there is more etiquette on stack overflow than there would be at a dinner with the queen ;)

Comment: @JohnWoods LOL - the point is that different questions require different knowledge. You want each question to get the attention it deserves and people that answer the question should get the credit they deserve. By posting a question as a comment to an answer, neither happens.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code casts `recognizer.view` to the `MyObject` type. This will let you access properties of `MyObject` using the dot `.` syntax.

Since Objective C is a dynamically typed language, type casting is less important than in strongly typed languages. You can call methods and access properties using square bracket syntax even without casting the variable to the `MyObject*` type. However, the correct type is necessary for accessing properties using the dot syntax.

Comment: Thank you, i'd upvote your answer but I don't have enough points to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it casts recognizer.view to a MyObject class.

Comment: Thank you, i'd upvote your answer but I don't have enough points to do so.